# How do you add to a Ruby array based on users input?

Tags: ruby, input, range

I am asking the user to input a number and based on that number I want to add certain players to my game.

```
class Player
  def players_playing
    players = []
    puts('How many players are playing?')
    players_amount = gets.chomp
    for i in range(players_amount)
      puts ('What is the players name')
      name = gets.chomp
      players.push(name)
    end
  end
end
```

So if they enter 3. Then the code should loop through 3 times and ask the user for names. e.g.

```
What is the players name? Rich
What is the players name? Tom
What is the players name? Charles
```

Then it would have players = ['Rich', 'Tom', 'Charles']

any ideas why my code is not correct? ( i figure it is to do with the `range` part maybe)

Comment: Where is `range` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:

At first you are asking for a number, however players_amount is a string. You should convert it using the `to_i` method.

Then, for iterating over a range, there are several ways of doing it in Ruby, but there is no keyword `range` as in Python. For iterating over a range (that is, an interval), use:

```
# Exclusive: 

(0...3).each do |i|
    puts i
end
# 0
# 1
# 2

# Inclusive:

(0..3).each do |i|
    puts i
end
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

So, instead of your for loop, just write `(0...players_amount).each do`.

With those modifications, the program has the expected behaviour. However, if you want the name to appear on the same line of the question, use `print` instead of `puts` because `puts` adds automatically a line break at the end of the string.

Comment: Please, edit the full code, and add the error you receive.

Comment: Unless you need the iteration number, I'd favour `x.to_i.times do ... end`

Answer (score 0):

I would add a complement to T. Claverie's answer. In this case I guess you only need to iterate a certain number of times and do nothing with the iteration index. That way, I would replace the `for` loop in your code with the following:

```
players_amount.times do
  puts ('What is the players name')
  name = gets.chomp
  players.push(name)
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You would still need to convert the string to an integer with `to_i`.